# redirection output to a file gives encoding issue in C

Tags: c, shell, redirect

I'm implementing a shell and working on redirection: writing output to a file or reading input from a file. the problems I'm facing are:

- The name of the file I'm getting is "**`b**" if I types this command as input to my program "**sort < test.txt**" while it shouldn't write to a file! and program hungs and no sorted output!
- If I typed: "**ls > out.txt**", the output is written to both terminal and *out.txt* file
- the program is expected to take input forever until the user write "exit" to close the program, however, after typing any command that needs redirection, the program stops, so it only do a cmd with redirection one time then it stop!

This is my code:

```
int execute(char **args)
{   
    int i, in, out;
    char * inputF;
    char * outputF;
    if (args[0] == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    int pNum = 0;
    //char * cwd;
    //cwd = getcurDirectory();
    i = 0;
    printf("***Testing: Before while loop\n"); 
    while (args[i] != NULL) {
    printf("***Testing: entered while loop: %d\n", i); 
        if (strcmp(args[i], "<") == 0) {
            printf("***Testing: found %s in args[%d] \n", args[i], i); 
            in = 1;
            args[i] = NULL;
            inputF = args[i+1];
            args[i+1] = NULL;
            ++i;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0) {
            printf("***Testing: found %s in args[%d] \n", args[i], i); 
            out = 1;
            args[i] = NULL;
            outputF = args[i+1];
            args[i+1] = NULL;
            ++i;
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0) {
            printf("***Testing: found %s in args[%d] \n", args[i], i); 
            ++pNum;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    if(in == 1 || out == 1){
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
                perror("fork");
        } else if (pid == 0) {   
            if (in) {
                int fd0 = open(inputF, O_RDONLY, 0);
                dup2(fd0, STDIN_FILENO);
                close(fd0);
                in = 0;
            }

            if (out) {
                int fd1 = creat(outputF, 0644);
                dup2(fd1, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd1);
                out = 0;
            } 
            int r; 
            for(r = 0; r < sizeof(args); ++r)
                printf("***Testing: args[%d] %s \n", r, args[r]); 
            //setenv("parent",cwd,1);
            if(execvp(args[0], args) < 0 ){
                perror(*args);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        } else {
            waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
            //free(args);
        }
    }

    if (pNum > 0){
        //printf("***Testing: Phew! got a pipe! \n");
        return handel_piping(args, pNum); 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < builtins(); i++) {
        if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
            return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
        }
    }

    return launch_cmd(args);
}
```

Comment: `for(r = 0; r < sizeof(args); ++r)` is wrong. `args` is a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof(args)` is the number of bytes in a pointer (usually 4 or 8 depending on the architecture).

Comment: Warning: `in` and `out` do not seem initialized.

Comment: @purplepsycho thank for your hint, appreciate it, I considered them in my solution, but I still have the same issues I mentioned in my post. any other hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're processing `<` and `>`, you're not incrementing `i` enough. Since these are followed by another argument, you need to increment `i` by 2, not 1, so it skips over the filename before processing the next argument.

```
    if (strcmp(args[i], "<") == 0) {
        printf("***Testing: found %s in args[%d] \n", args[i], i); 
        in = 1;
        args[i] = NULL;
        inputF = args[i+1];
        args[i+1] = NULL;
        i += 2;
        continue;
    }

    if (strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0) {
        printf("***Testing: found %s in args[%d] \n", args[i], i); 
        out = 1;
        args[i] = NULL;
        outputF = args[i+1];
        args[i+1] = NULL;
        i += 2;
        continue;
    }
```

Another problem is that you don't initialize `in` and `out`. Since they're unlikely to be initialized to `0`, the code will act as if you'd typed a redirection that you didn't, and then use an uninitialized variable as the filename. They should be initialized with:

```
int i, in = 0, out = 0;
```

This loop is wrong:

```
        for(r = 0; r < sizeof(args); ++r)
            printf("***Testing: args[%d] %s \n", r, args[r]);
```

`sizeof(args)` is the size of a pointer, not the number of elements in the `args` array. And it also tries to print arguments that have been replaced with `NULL` by the earlier loop. It should be:

```
        for(r = 0; args[r] != 0; ++r)
            printf("***Testing: args[%d] %s \n", r, args[r]);
```

Comment: these are great hints, many thanks! however, I still have same issues mentioned above and I can't figure out where is the problem :\

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you're seeing the output on the terminal when it's redirected to a file.

Comment: There's no way that could happen without using a program like `tee`.

Comment: I'm not going to debug a 400-line program for you. You've got a debugger, learn to use it.